# Is there any way to debug web applications using Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, web-applications

I am working on a web application using the Eclipse Java IDE.

I am using Tomcat 6 as my servlet container.

The tools available for Java, inculding Eclipse, seem to lack debugging capabilities for web applicatons (as compared to Visual Studio for the .NET platform).

How can I debug my web app using Eclipse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

run tomcat in debug mode (java option `-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000`) and then use remote debug in Eclipse (Debug Configurations -> Remote Java Aplication) and connect to server on configured port (e.g. 8000 in this example).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to debug your web application, set breakpoints where desired and run Tomcat on **debug** mode. If you logged your exceptions or placed `INFO`/`DEBUG` messages, you can view them on `Console` (if `ConsoleAppender` is used).

The essential thing is that your application runs on debug mode.
For browser side debugging (as @Thomas said), there's tools like Chrome Debugger (for Google Chrome), [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) (for Firefox) and Firebug Lite (for other browsers).

Comment: Yes, running on debug mode is essential. For Browserside debugging (Javascript etc.) there are tools like Firebug etc, since the server can't know what the client really does there.

Answer (score 0):

You can add breakpoint in you code and deploy the application in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse has a console window where you can see the error messages generated. For the web there are an add ons or built on the browser like firebug for Firefox and Google-chrome developers-tools. Try too look on it.